# Translations of common application strings

Tags: localization

*Ok, quick points for someone who is better at searching than I am...*

I **know** I have seen before a list of translations of common application strings like "File," "Open," "Save," "Close," and "OK," into other languages. This was not just a scrape of Google translator, but an actual "official" list based on the localized OS. It seems to me that it was on Microsoft's site, but I'm not 100% sure.

I need to translate my application into Indonesian and wanted to give our translators a head start by filling in those common terms with the standard values, but now I cannot find the web page(s)! I've spent about 15 minutes and will continue to search (and will post the answer if I find it), but if someone else knows where that is (or finds it first!), please answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Microsoft Language Portal](http://www.microsoft.com/Language)

Comment: The only problem with this, is that it's based on Microsoft products, so it's still difficult to decipher which is which.

Comment: Link is back for anyone wondering

Comment: Link is dead again. It will force you to sign up, only to say there is nothing at that link.